# Check and replace stuff

Tags: javascript, string, discord, discord.js

Hi I am trying to make a server requirement system. so if message is `https://discord.gg/IDhE5ire` How to replace only https://discord.gg and keep the rest?

Thats all i want to know. If anyone has solution to this. Please answer :3

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

Example:

```
let link = "https://discord.gg/IDhE5ire";
let result = link.replace("https://discord.gg/", ""); //IDhE5ire
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.replace()`

```js
const str = 'https://discord.gg/IDhE5ire'
const filteredStr = str.replace('https://discord.gg/', '') // Outputs `IDhE5ire`
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers work but a good one to also note is `.split`:

```js
const invite = "https://discord.gg/IDhE5ire";
const arr = invite.split(".gg/");
const code = arr[1];

console.log(code, arr);
```